# How can I trigger jenkins jobs with a slack bot?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bots, slack

I have Jenkins running on one of the VMs on GCP. I have a bunch of jobs and I want to give my team access to run them from Slack. They haven't used Jenkins earlier, and not at all familiar with the UI. So, they want to run it from Slack. We already have a slack bot. So, here are my following questions:

1. Can I integrate our existing slackbot with jenkins, so that it can trigger the jobs? If yes, how can I do it? (any tutorial would be greatly appreciated)
2. I know there is a way to do this with slash commands. But I don't want run a different command for each job, it's actually not really clean. Cause if I have 20 jobs, I have to create tokens for all of them, and configure 20 slash commands.
3. What are the other ways of triggering Jenkins jobs from Slack?

PS: I'm looking for something like @bot run "job" "parameter" or @bot run "job". And it would be great if the bot can tag the user and respond to a request

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a slack app for this and enable events and interactivity.

https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api#the-events-api__subscribing-to-event-types__events-api-request-urls__request-url-configuration--verification__url-verification-handshake